# How to concatenate date in INFILE when there is date in filename

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I use SQL*Loader to upload file in table. When filename is hard-coded in format `FILE_20200610.csv` all working just fine but now I need to figure out how to use dates daily basis in `INFILE`.

I have tried several different ways but always something goes wrong. Is this even possible to use date in filenames in control file?

Latest version I tried was:

```
INFILE '/dir1/dir2/FILE_'date+"%YYYY%MM%DD"'.csv
```

It didnt work.

This works:

```
INFILE '/dir1/dir2/FILE_20200610.csv'
```

How I can solve this? Is my format totally wrong?

Thank you.

Regards, New with Loader

Comment: The reaso it doesn't work in your control file is because sqlldr (the executable that is reading and interpreting the control file) does not know how to parse _os commands_.  In this case the os command is your use of 'date+"%YYYY%MM%DD'  As @Roberto Hernandez shows, you'd need to have the shell process that 'date' function, and pass the result on the sqlldr command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly.

One option is to "dynamically" create a control file using some other tool (for example, in MS Windows, that would be a batch (.BAT) script).

Another is to switch to an external table; as it is just a `CREATE TABLE` statement, you can create it *dynamically* as well (using `execute immediate`) by changing only the source file name.

Comment: In fact, if using a recent DB version, you can just create the external table once, and modify the location on the fly, look at the 'modified_external_table' part in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you will have to use Shell Script (Linux/Unix) or Powershell (Windows) to run the SqlLoader program. In your case, it looks like it is Linux/Unix, so why don't use bash capabilities for it.

You have to leave the control file without date.

```
INFILE '/dir1/dir2/FILE.csv'
```

And in your shell, something like that

```
if [[ -f /dir1/dir2/FILE_`date +%Y%m%d`.csv ]]; 
then 
    mv -f /dir1/dir2/FILE_`date +%Y%m%d`.csv /dir1/dir2/FILE.csv 2>&1
end if;

-- run sql loader
```